# Solspace Tag and sorting by tags from tag group

Tags: tags, solspace-tag, sorting

I have created tags group "Attributes", which contain tags for product colors, material which was made etc. Next I want to sort products by one of tag from that group (a drop down menu "sort by" and there are listed all tags from that group).

I know how to display all tags from that group, but I'm not able to retrieve tags for displayed products only (for an example there is no red color so shouldn't be displayed).

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to display tags for a defined list of entries, which in turn are listed using {exp:channel:entries}?

Comment: Correct - all existing tags from the `channel:entries`

Comment: Wouldn't `{exp:tag:tags}` do the job then? http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/tags/ You would feed it an entry_id of course: `{exp:tag:tags entry_id="{entry_id}"}`